# sharepoint online custom web part with jquery to realize multi-comments

Tags: sharepoint-online

As we know, we can enable comments in the sharepoint admin center, but it just shows in the bottom of sharepoint modern page.

I want to realize custom webpart and add more than one comments in a sharepoint mordern page as below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSKaT.png)

can any helps?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The built-in page comment web part in SPO modern UI has not been exposed, we can't make use of it. We need to develop a custom SPFx web part. There is a plugin "[jquery-comments](https://viima.github.io/jquery-comments/)", we can use it in the webpart. Please take a reference of below demo:

- https://github.com/kongmengfei/SharedSPFx/blob/master/js-advanced-commenting/README.md

Test Result:

[image]

Related references:

1. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/sharepoint-framework-community-call-recording-12th-of-march-2020/

Comment: thanks,baker, i have successfully added the custom web part!!

Comment: after deploying this apps, i can add it to my web site and use it in my page